# Javascript document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML mktree works on Firefox but not on Chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a Google Maps application in development at https://sites.google.com/site/collectinginterests/somerset-post-offices.  The side bar is built dynamically and uses mktree (from http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/mktree/) to collapse the view.

The page displays OK (ie. collapses the side bar) in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE where the unordered lists are displayed in full (no [+] buttons) - at least for me.  I have noticed that occasionally in Firefox the side bar does not format correctly but it is OK on a reload of the page. No errors spotted in the javascript console.

I've captured the dynamically created side bar HTML, put it in a test page and this displays fine in all three browsers.

I realise I haven't included any code snippets but I'm at a loss as to which bits would be relevant, especially as the side bar html works OK stand-alone.

**More debugging later:**  I put the side bar in as static html (using exactly the same html that I extracted from when it was created dynamically) and it works on all three browsers (ie. compacts down and shows the [+] buttons).

So my problem seems to stem from using

```
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar;
```

and it not getting fully processed by Chrome and IE (& occasionally by Firefox), perhaps associated with all the other processing being done to populate the google map.

The web page into which this element is being reloaded is:

```
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
      <td>
         <div id="map" style="width: 950px; height: 750px"></div>
      </td>
      <td width = 300 valign="top" style="color: #4444ff;">
         <div id="side_bar"  style="overflow:auto; height:750px;">
           *** static HTML inserted here and it works
         </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**Yet more debugging later:** I've tried moving the processing around so that I create and rewrite the sidebar before calling Google Maps to create the map and plot the markers and it still does not properly format the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem: You have two pieces of code that don't always execute in the same order.

There is a `getPlaces()` function which is called via a gadget onload handler:

```
gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(getPlaces);
```

This function issues an asynchronous request with `gotPlaces` for the callback:

```
gadgets.io.makeRequest(url, gotPlaces, params);
```

`gotPlaces()` calls `Load_Arrays()`, which then calls `Create_Sidebar()`.

`Create_Sidebar()` is where you insert the sidebar innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar;
```

This `innerHTML` works fine in all cases; it isn't the problem.

Now what you're hoping to have happen after this is for `convertTrees()` to be called. This function calls `processList()` to set up the classes on each of your ULs.

How does `convertTrees()` get called? From another onload handler - and a different kind of onload handler:

```
addEvent(window,"load",convertTrees);
```

But in the case where you don't get the lists properly collapsed, `convertTrees()` was called too early - before `CreateSidebar()`.

It's not surprising that this is fairly nondeterministic.

How to fix it?

I think the easiest thing might be to remove the onload handler for `convertTrees()`, and instead call this function directly from the code at the right time. For example you could call `convertTrees()` at the end of `Load_Arrays()` right after the `Create_Sidebar()` call.

BTW, if you can break out of this Google Gadget prison and test your code in an ordinary non-Gadget HTML page, it will make it a lot easier to debug the code. It's hard to use ordinary developer tools like Firebug or the Chrome DevTools with the gadget code, because they load your actual code through an `<iframe>` whose URL changes frequently. And when that happens you lose any breakpoints you've set under the old URL.

Of course if you're editing the code yourself, you can just use a `debugger;` statement where you want a breakpoint instead of clicking in the debugger like I was doing - so in practice this may not really be a problem.

Comment: I'd almost spotted it when your post came in.  I've removed the event handler that calls convertTrees and called it myself after creting the sidebar and it works great. I do test the code locally rather than in the Google Gadget prison (but am still getting to grips with Firebug).